# Pycharm error: Cannot determine module type ("WEB_MODULE")

Tags: pycharm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm using Pycharm Professional 4.5.4 to develop a javascript project and was seeing some odd behaviour when opening the project in the browser.

The project structure is something like

```
/MyProject
    /data
    /images
    /python
    /etc
    /webapp
    /webapp_copy
```

I was trying out a few changes in the webapp_copy folder, but when I launched in the browser, pycharm launched the webapp version of the site. No idea why it was doing this, maybe because the structure and contents were similar.

Anyway, I closed the project and reopened just the webapp_copy folder. Now I'm getting the error Cannot determine module type ("WEB_MODULE") for the following module:"webapp_copy".

When I browse the .idea folder and look at webapp_copy.iml, is does indeed say

```
<module type="WEB_MODULE" version="4">
```

Why would Pycharm label this module as a web module, then later claim it doesn't know what a web module is?

I've tried searching, but I either get results for IntelliJ or something about python modules.
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/supported-module-types.html

UPDATE:
I've raised this as an issue with JetBrains - feel free to vote on it!
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-17084

Comment: The link to `supported-module-types` now redirects to `creating-and-managing-modules` which has no list of known types, nor any notes on how to change the type. :(

Comment: Perhaps this alternate: https://gerardnico.com/ide/idea/module#list

Answer (score 40, accepted):

When I had a similar problem (type="RUBY_MODULE") it was because I had opened the directory containing the code originally using RubyMine so it created the .idea directory/content based on what it supports.

I don't know if you (or someone else) originally used something else that created the .idea directory so YMMV, but per the link you listed, the WEB_MODULE type only seems to apply to IntelliJ Ultimate.

To fix this, simply change the type to PYTHON_MODULE in the .iml file, restart PyCharm and the warning should go away.  If you are, in fact, using IntelliJ, you should be fine as PYTHON_MODULE is supported by the Ultimate edition per your link (although you may have to install a specific python add-in).

Comment: Yep, it just occurred to me last night that the webapp folder was copied from my colleague's machine - he uses Webstorm, not Pycharm, so that's why the folder was labelled as a web module. D'oh!

Comment: I guess Pycharm (and others) only read the .idea folder in the root directory and ignore all the subfolders. Is that right?

Comment: Worked for me too, under a slightly different case.  
I had initially created the project using WebStorm, later shifted to RubyMine, but code highlighting messed up because of this module type problem I believe. Upon changing `WEB_MODULE` to `RUBY_MODULE` in `.idea/[project-name].iml` file, it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

It's worked for me just by remove directory `.idea` and reopen Pycharm.